# Imported method will not work unless full class path is used

Tags: java, maven

I am having trouble with a method that can be accessed using the full class path, but if I try and import it and call the method, it says that method is not defined for the current class. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: The error]

"The method equalTo(int) is undefined for the type App"

Comment: Unless you statically import the method the unqualified form is not available for use

Comment: What do you mean by "import it"? if the method is static, you can import the class to the project and you can access the method by Classname.methodName()

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to call the method like the line 7 of your screenshot indicates, you would need to use static import:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
```

This will allow you to call the method as you seem to need:

```
equalTo(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import static  org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

you need to define static imports. The equalTo(T) is a static method.

Or you can access it with class name like:

```
Matchers.equalTo(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a method directly. You need to specify the class that has this method.

You should change your import to "org.harmcrest.Matchers"

And use: "Matchers.equalTo(5);"

Unless, of course, you use "import static", like the others users have shown. :)